# Any news of more write APIs?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, write-access

It's been a while since I was last here. Is there any news on further updates to the API? (I'm specifically thinking about adding more write methods.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write methods have been added to an unreleased version of the API that's used by the [official (albeit in-development) Android app](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/190200/help-us-test-the-alpha-version-of-our-android-app?rq=1), so it's expected that they'll be made available at some point after that app (and perhaps the one for iPhone) are released to the general public.

…which has now happened. Various write methods are available as of [the 2.2 release of the API](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/02/stack-exchange-api-v2-2-and-the-demise-of-v1-x/), provided you have an auth token with `write_access` scope.